# Sitecore SXA Location search Limit results by Country

Tags: sxa

we are currently using Sitecore 9.0.2 with SXA 1.8.1

Is there a way to limit the Auto-complete on the Location finder to a particular country or city?

Comment: No, there is no such possibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a project I worked on we created a custom Maps Connector theme. We copied the script provided OOTB with SXA, renamed it, then made some changes to it.

Here is an example of how we changed it so the country was included:

```javascript
autocomplete.getPlacePredictions({
    input: queryParams.text,
    'componentRestrictions': {
        'country': 'us'
    },
    'types': ['geocode']
}, function(results) {
    var predictions = [],
        length;
    if (results != null && results.length) {
        length = results.length >= maxResults ? maxResults : results.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            predictions.push(_.extend(results[i], {
                text: results[i].description
            }));
        }

        console.log("Adding predictions to storage.");
        sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(predictions));
        successCallback(predictions);
    } else {
        failCallback();
    }
});
```